# how to pass data from controller to view using ajax in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, laravel

I have simple table for my tags.

Route

```
route::resource('admin/tags','TagController');
```

Controller :

```
    public function index()
{
    $tags=Tag::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('products.tag',compact('tags'));
}
```

View :

```
@extends('admin.index')
@section('content')
 ...html code...
<table class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th scope="col">#</th>
     <th scope="col">tag name</th>
     <th scope="col">tag slug</th>
     <th scope="col">description</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($tags as $tag)
 <tr>
  <th scope="row">{{$tag->id}}</th>
  <td>{{$tag->tag_name}}</td>
  <td>{{$tag->tag_slug}}</td>
  <td>@{{$tag->tag_description}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
  <div class="paging site-pagination">
     {{$tags->links()}}
 </div>
 ...html code...
  @endsection
```

Now, this code work like charm but I want to get data from ajax ,then pass to my view.

My ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(() => {
   get_data()

function get_data() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/admin/tags',
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log('before')
        },
        success: function (data , status , xhr){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status );
            console.log(xhr);
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            console.log('complete')
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('error')
        },
    });
}
 )}
```

Well.now my success function is Work and get my html.
but I just want to get `tags` variable and pass it to view.

I change my controller like this:

```
//return view('admin.pages.products.tag',compact('tags'));
  return response()->json($tags);
```

Now my tag view is:

```
{
 "current_page": 1,
"data": [
{
 "id": 46,
 "tag_name": "EbTLzDikpS",
 "tag_slug": "mKXcpVOF3L",
 "tag_description": "05HMeVazYO",
},
  ...
{
 "id": 5,
 "tag_name": "T4uvmukgZA",
 "tag_slug": "fpWwimnnIk",
  "tag_description": "A0nfZ4POHR",
 }
 ],
"first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/tags?page=1",
"from": 1,
"last_page": 10,
"last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/tags?page=10",
"next_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/tags?page=2",
"path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/tags",
"per_page": "5",
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": 5,
"total": 46
}
```

Now even if I delete my ajax function still my view not change.

So i change again my controller :

```
return view ('admin.pages.products.tag', compact('tags'))->render();
```

Still not work.

Comment: The `get` request wouldn't know what to do with the `view()`. So it's better to create api routes and controllers and let the ajax request go to the api routes. Then in the api controller only return the result of `$tags`.

Comment: Hi buddy.I don't know how to work with ' api routes'. So you Mean There's Not any way?

Comment: If you look in the routes folder you have a `web.php` and `api.php` files. When creating a route or resource route in the `api.php` you need to prefix those routes with `/api/` so if you would normally use `url: '/admin/tags'` with an api you use: `url: '/api/admin/tags'`. It is also recommended to make a new controller. You can do this by creating a new folder `api` in the controller folder already there. Now you can use a setting somewhere (can't remember where) to point all api routes to this new controller folder

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to give the name of `function(method)` for your Route:

`route::resource('admin/tags','TagController@index');`

Your code is look like API, but you can use `api/admin/tags` if you are in route/web.php

If your problem is till, then change the function :

```js
 public function index()
{
    $tags=Tag::latest()->paginate(5);
    return response()->json($tags);
}
```

Comment: The route thing is the first problem I tought too but when defined as a resource Laravel automatically knows it should be `store, update, index` etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right, let him correct route and what will be result. Actually i have checked whole this code. @SuperDJ

Comment: Hi. my controller is resource so there's no need for function name and laravel automatically know it means index functions.